# How to make "defered" value export with MEF?

Tags: wpf, inversion-of-control, mef, ioc-container, caliburn.micro

I have a Caliburn Micro's bootstrapper and I use the MEF as IoC. One of interfaces implementors can throw exception from it's constructor. So, when I do the following:

```
 CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch();
 batch.AddExportedValue<IFrProvider>(new ShtrihFr());
```

Then I get exception at application startup, but I want to get it at the time of resolvation.
How to accomplish that with MEF?

Update 1.

Here what I did:

```
[Export(typeof (LoadingViewModel))]
public class LoadingViewModel {    
    public LoadingViewModel() {}

    [Import]
    private readonly IFrProvider frProvider;
 }

[Export(typeof(IFrProvider))]
public class ShtrihFr : IFrProvider {
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShtrihFr(int password = 1) {          
    }
}
```

So when I do the following:

```
 protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key) {
        string contract = string.IsNullOrEmpty(key) ? AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(serviceType) : key;
        IEnumerable<object> exports = container.GetExportedValues<object>(contract);

        var exportedList = exports as IList<object> ?? exports.ToList();
        if (exportedList.Any())
            return exportedList.First();

        throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not locate any instances of contract {0}.", contract));
    }
```

exportedList count is 0. It can't find the implementation. I cheked that the container has amidts it's parts the ShtrihFr implementation. How to solve the problem?

Update 2.
For debugging purpose I did added the following to the beggining of GetInstance method:

```
if (serviceType.FullName == "Microtech.Hardware.IFrProvider") {
            var export = container.GetExport<IFrProvider>();
            var frProvider = export.Value;
}
```

At line container.GetExport I get ImportCardinalityMismatchException. No exports were found that match the constraint...

Comment: The issue was with constructor which takes int value. It should be exported for MEF as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is the following. On application startup create `Catalog` that contains all composable parts of your application and initialize the `CompositionContainer`.  Here is the code.

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path to the directory that contains your dlls, "*.dll");
var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
compositionContainer.ComposeParts();
```

Next mark your `ShtrihFr` class with `Export` attribute:

```
[Export(typeof(IFrProvider))]
public class ShtrihFr : IFrProvider
{
    public ShtrihFr()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Not Implemented");
    }
}
```

This way the `CompositionContainer` through the `DirectoryCatalog` will only get list of composable parts and their contracts. Actual instances will not be created, so you won't get exception on application startup.

When you need instance of the `ShtrihFr` class, you can use one of the following lines:

```
var part = compositionContainer.GetExportedValue<IFrProvider>();
```

The above line will throw exception if the constructor throws exception, which is the case now.

```
var part = compositionContainer.GetExport<IFrProvider>();
```

The above line will not throw exception when executed, but to get the actual instance you will need to access the `Value` property of the `part` variable, which will throw exception.

**Update 1:**

Add default constructor to the `ShtrihFr` class, so it look like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IFrProvider))]
public class ShtrihFr : IFrProvider 
{
    public ShtrihFr(int password = 1) 
    {          
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ShtrihFr(int password = 1) 
    {          
    }
}
```

And instead of using the overridden `GetInstance` method, use something like this,  if you need collection of exported parts:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetInstances<T>(Type constraint = null)
{
    if (constraint == null)
        return compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<T>();

    return compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<T>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(constraint));
}
```

or something like this, if you need single exported part:

```
public T GetInstance<T>(Type constraint = null)
{
    if (constraint == null)
        return compositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>();

    return compositionContainer.GetExportedValue<T>(AttributedModelServices.GetContractName(constraint));
}
```

In both methods, the type parametar `T` is the type of the exported part you want to instantiate. The `constraint` parameter passed to both methods is additional constraint that is optional and if needed is applied to the `Export` attribute of the classes.